# Can this self-join be optimized further?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, self-join

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to optimize the query containing a self-join, and if it is possible - how to do it.

I'm working on a bigger real-life task, but here I extracted a simple sub-task from it to keep focus on a particular issue: optimizing a self-join query.

I have a table called `parties`. It contains over 85k records and looks like this:

```
# \d test.parties
                  Table "test.parties"
   Column    | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | uuid |           |          |
 contract_id | uuid |           |          |
```

Doing a self-join on `contract_id` I get this plan:

```
# explain analyse select p1.id from test.parties p1 join test.parties p2 on p1.contract_id = p2.contract_id;
                                                         QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=20207.87..628157.87 rows=40500000 width=16) (actual time=109.709..184.523 rows=197632 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (p1.contract_id = p2.contract_id)
   ->  Sort  (cost=11181.94..11406.94 rows=90000 width=32) (actual time=55.560..66.173 rows=86332 loops=1)
         Sort Key: p1.contract_id
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3560kB
         ->  Seq Scan on parties p1  (cost=0.00..1620.00 rows=90000 width=32) (actual time=0.018..14.518 rows=86332 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=9025.94..9250.94 rows=90000 width=16) (actual time=54.135..74.973 rows=197631 loops=1)
         Sort Key: p2.contract_id
         Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 2544kB
         ->  Seq Scan on parties p2  (cost=0.00..1620.00 rows=90000 width=16) (actual time=0.009..10.462 rows=86332 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.167 ms
 Execution Time: 199.677 ms
(12 rows)
```

Adding an index on `contract_id` I get this plan:

```
# create index on test.parties(contract_id);
CREATE INDEX
# explain analyse select p1.id from test.parties p1 join test.parties p2 on p1.contract_id = p2.contract_id;
                                                         QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=3084.47..10570.76 rows=192484 width=16) (actual time=32.457..97.662 rows=197632 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (p1.contract_id = p2.contract_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on parties p1  (cost=0.00..1583.32 rows=86332 width=32) (actual time=0.013..11.293 rows=86332 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1583.32..1583.32 rows=86332 width=16) (actual time=32.133..32.133 rows=86332 loops=1)
         Buckets: 131072  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 3048kB
         ->  Seq Scan on parties p2  (cost=0.00..1583.32 rows=86332 width=16) (actual time=0.007..12.815 rows=86332 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.444 ms
 Execution Time: 110.692 ms
(8 rows)
```

Is there a way I could get rid of those `Seq Scan`s?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the presence of any index in your explain plan, so assign that you have *not* yet looked into using indices, here is one suggestion:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON parties (contract_id, id);
```

This should speed up the join, and it also covers the `id` value, which is required in the `SELECT` clause.